# How to know/get the capacity of hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am curious, I read in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) :

> The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table ... The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

Is there a way to know the capacity (number of buckets) of the hashmap at an instant t?

Comment: No, it is not available. You can go through reflection though. But there must not be any need to get the capacity of a hashmap. Size fulfills all the requirements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need reflection

```
HashMap m = new HashMap();
Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
tableField.setAccessible(true);
Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(m);
System.out.println(table == null ? 0 : table.length);
```

Comment: This is resulting to 0. I tested in java 1.7 . It should have return 16 as initial capacity for hashmap is 16.

Comment: It seems it became lazy in 1.7. Try   HashMap m = new HashMap();
  m.put(1, 1);

Comment: Great Thanks :) Does this means java 1.7 onwards if you don't put any entry(key,valu) in hashmap, the initial capacity remains 0 and default capacity is not 16??

Comment: I have now tested with older versions (1.4, 1.6). It is giving 0 unless you put an entry in hashmap.

Comment: 1) table == null ? 0 : table.length is giving 0 because table = null --- not created until first accessed 2) I am sure this worked when I answered it in 2014, otherwise it wouldnt be accepted

Comment: Yes i again installed java6 and tried out there it gives 16 as initial capacity without any element too. This was changed in 1.7 thanks :)

Comment: perfectly working with java-8

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [online API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), you'll see that there aren't any publicly available methods that will tell you that. There's always reflection, but I wouldn't recommend that.

In any case, that could be considered an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

No such public method in `HashMap`.

You could use **debug mode** in your IDE to watch `HashMap.table`.

plus: as Sanjeev commented, reflection is an option.